# Showing Error when i try to upload list of images which have Iterable<ImageFile> type

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using [multi_image_picker_view](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker_view)  which return Iterable and i Add it into My List images; Like this

```
onChange: (p0) {
image.add(File(p0.toString()));
},
```

i want to Upload this Image List to My Server but showing error on image.File[i].path:

> FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = '[Instance of 'ImageFile', Instance of 'ImageFile', Instance of 'ImageFile', Instance of 'ImageFile']' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2))

i try to print my image List and the result was

[File: '[Instance of 'ImageFile', Instance of 'ImageFile', Instance of 'ImageFile', Instance of 'ImageFile', Instance of 'ImageFile']']
this is my function where i try to send array of my images to my server

```
uploadsurveryImage(List\<File\> imageFile) async {
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(FORM_URL));
for (var i = 0; i \< imageFile.length; i++) {
request.files.add(http.MultipartFile(
'gallery',
File(imageFile\[i\].path).readAsBytes().asStream(),
// showing error here when reading the length of images
File(imageFile\[i\].path).lengthSync(),
filename: basename(imageFile\[i\].path.split("/").last)));
}
var response = await request.send();
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
return 'done'
} else {
return 'Something Wrong';
}

}
```

i just want to upload images to my server

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing this: `image.add(File(p0.toString()));` The `.toString` method doesn't give you a path, it returns a string that **represents** the *object*.

Instead, use the `path` property from the `ImageFile` class.

So, this should work:
`image.add(File(p0.path));`